# Show a double-sided infinite integral of $\sin(x+b)$ exists iff $b=n\pi$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, proof-writing

More formally: 
Show that $$\lim_{a\rightarrow \infty} \int_{-a}^a \sin(x+b)$$ exists if and only if $b=n\pi$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I get the intuition fine. The function is just a horizontal translate so if the double infinite integral is to exist, both 'sides' (around 0) should be equal to each other. If we think of the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$, then it's obvious that the two 'sides' are equal iff $b=n\pi$. I just don't know how to formalize this intuition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not compute the integral exactly?

$\int_{-a}^{a} dx \sin(x+b) = \cos(-a+b)-\cos(a+b) = 2 \sin(b) \sin(a)$. If $b = n \pi$, the value is $0$ as $a \rightarrow \infty$. If $b \neq n \pi$, the value of the integral is oscillating as $a \rightarrow \infty$, and the limit does not exist.

Comment: Perfect. That was obvious.

Answer (score 4):

Just compute the integral directly:

\begin{align*}
\int_{-a}^a \sin(x + b) &= -\cos(x + b) \Big|_{-a}^a \\
&= \cos(b - a) - \cos(b + a)
\end{align*}

Now using standard identities for the cosine of a sum / difference, we get

\begin{align*}
\cos b \cos a + \sin b \sin a - \Big(\cos b \cos a - \sin b \sin a\Big) &= 2 \sin b \sin a
\end{align*}

Now if $\sin b \ne 0$, the oscillation of the sine function causes the limit to not exist - but if $\sin b = 0$, the limit is obvious.

Comment: Perfect -- thank you. I gave the answer check to user51524 -- you guys had identical answers but he beat you by a second. Thank you though!